# Why at the Account tab dropdown menu the "+ Account" option is missing? (applies to ANY other tab, too)

Tags: lightning-experience, tab, create-records, ui, new

**Update**: this issue applies to ANY SObject tab (Custom + Standard), too.

On all Orgs but one that I know at the Account tab there is a first option "+ New Account". It looks always like this and this is the expected behavior:

[image]

Now on one bad Org the Account tab just looks like that and the desired "+ New Account" option seems to be lost:

[image]

I am sure, that some time ago it was there. I can't remember that we have changed anything. On other tabs (e.g. Contact) the "+ New Contact" option is available:

[image]

Is there any way to get that "+ New Account" option back??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this one is very wired and I would consider it as a Salesforce BUG. But maybe it is just a feature, that I can not understand.

In the setup, you can configure Account > Search Layouts. There the first row called "Search Results". It is strange, but I have learned already that "Search Result" has impact on the "Recent Items" shown by default for any tab, so I went there to check:

[image]

Now we have added a custom button to "Mass Delete" records on nearly ANY object in Salesforce and I have added this button to "Search Results" in the desperate hope that it might add the "Mass Delete" feature also to the "Recent Items" list for the tab.

[image]

But not only that the "Mass Delete" button is never showing for the "Recent Items", the selection of the button is killing the "+ New ..." for the tab. Removing the custom button also brings back the "+ New ..." option.

The expected behavior would be to

- get the Mass Delete button also in the recent list
- never to loose the "+ New ..." option by adding an additional button

So BUG or feature? I don't know...

Comment: this is a bug for sure